# Combine 3 SQL queries into 1

Tags: sql, linq

I have 3 queries that I need combined into one. Here they are

```
SELECT COUNT(e.EmployeeID) AS TotalEmpCount
FROM Employees as e
WHERE HomePhone <> ''

SELECT COUNT(e.EmployeeID) AS USEmpCount
FROM Employees as e
INNER JOIN Orders as o ON e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID
WHERE e.HomePhone <> '' AND e.Country='US' AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN '11/01/2011' AND GETDATE()


SELECT COUNT(e.EmployeeID) AS UKEmpCount
FROM Employees as e
INNER JOIN Orders as o ON e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID
WHERE HomePhone <> '' AND Country ='UK' AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN '01/01/2011' AND '12/31/2012'
```

I need to have one query that returns 3 columns: TotalEmpCount, USEmpCount, UKEmpCount.

I need this query in T-SQL as well as Linq format

Comment: You can improve your question by asking a question... and showing what you've done (your 1 query) and what kind of errors you are getting.

Comment: If i already had one query, I probably would not be asking a question in the first place.

Comment: Showing your attempt and asking how you can improve it or make it work is much better than telling us what you need and expecting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out myself:

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Employees as e
WHERE HomePhone <> ''
        ) AS TotalEmpCount,
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Employees as e
INNER JOIN Orders as o ON e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID
WHERE e.HomePhone <> '' AND e.Country='US' AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN '11/01/2011' AND GETDATE()
        )  AS USEmpCount,
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Employees as e
INNER JOIN Orders as o ON e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID
WHERE HomePhone <> '' AND Country ='UK' AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN '01/01/2011' AND '12/31/2012'
        )  AS UKEmpCount
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the same result:

```
SELECT COUNT(e.EmployeeID) AS TotalEmpCount,
    USEmpCount = SUM(CASE WHEN e.Country='US' AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN '11/01/2011' AND GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    UKEmpCount = SUM(CASE WHEN e.Country ='UK' AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN '01/01/2011' AND '12/31/2012' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Employees as e
LEFT JOIN Orders o
    ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
WHERE HomePhone <> ''
```